# Bayesian Wilcoxon test

Tags: bayesian, t-test, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a pre-post dataset with 2 observations per subject (propotion data -bounded between 0 and 1-).

I have analyzed the data with a classical dependent t-test under the NHST paradigm. However, as data does not follow normality and I have a relatively small sample size (i.e., 10 subjects), the p-value may be unreliable. In the NHST framework it is typical conducting a Wilcoxon test afterwards in order to compare both distributions.

However, I want to conduct the analysis with Bayesian statistics due to its simple interpretation (i.e., in probability terms). Is there any equivalent to the Wilcoxon test (or in general non-parametric statistical tests) in Bayesian statistics?

Comment: Is this "before and after" data?

Comment: Yes it is a within subjects experiment

Comment: Is there a reason you do not believe it to be normal?  With such a small sample size, you shouldn't be able to tell from the data.

Comment: There is such a thing. See Ferguson (1973) "A Bayesian analysis of some nonparametric problems" in The Annals of Statistics. He introduces the Dirichlet Process. If you're not familiar with this stuff, it probably won't be helpful. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to provide an answer that would illustrate what to do.

Comment: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/benavoli14.pdf

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610926.2017.1388402?journalCode=lsta20 See this paper by Chechile for a Bayesian Wilcoxon analysis.